# MVC EF - How to save Array to db

Tags: arrays, json, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to save an array of tags which I pass from view to controller using angular and json. I tried the following but vm.Name comes up as null.

**script post request**

```
$http({
method: 'POST',
url: '/RecipeTags/CreateRecipeTag',
data: $scope.selectedTags
}).then(function (response) {
}, function () { alert('Error CreateRecipeTag'); });
```

**sample array**

```
[{"Id":12,"Name":"Baking","RecipeId":0},{"Id":16,"Name":"Oriental","RecipeId":0},{"Id":17,"Name":"Japanese","RecipeId":0}]
```

**RecipeTagsController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CreateRecipeTag(List<RecipeTag> vm)
    {

        foreach (var tag in vm)
        {
            RecipeTag recipeTag = new RecipeTag();
            recipeTag.Name = vm.Name;
            recipeTag.RecipeId = vm.RecipeId;
            db.RecipeTags.Add(recipeTag);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(vm, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**RecipeTag.cs**

```
public class RecipeTag
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Tag")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Recipe")]
    public int RecipeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your action signature only accepts one item rather than a collection. Also, have you examined the request details for the posted data?

Comment: @Jasen If I changed it to `public JsonResult CreateRecipeTag(List<RecipeTag> vm)` `vm.Name` and `vm.RecipeId ` returns an error that says List<RecipeTag> does not contain a definition for the `'vm.Name'` and `'vm.RecipeId'`

Comment: If `vm` is now a list, then `foreach(var tag in vm) { recipieTag.Name = tag.Name; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Jasen said I changed my action signature to a collection and changed `vm.RecipeId` to `tag.RecipeId`and I also made the `ActionResult` asynchronous and it finally worked! Thanks!

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> CreateRecipeTag([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,RecipeId")] List<RecipeTag> vm)
        {
            foreach (var tag in vm)
            {
                RecipeTag recipeTag = new RecipeTag();
                recipeTag.RecipeId = tag.RecipeId;
                recipeTag.Name = tag.Name;
                db.RecipeTags.Add(recipeTag);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define RecipeTag as DataContract.

Something like this:

```
// Service definition
[ServiceContract(Name = "Service1")]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract,HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CreateRecipeTag(List<MyRecipeTag> vm);
}

// DataType-Definition for the Service
[DataContract]
public class MyRecipeTag
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int RecipeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
}

// Service implementation
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CreateRecipeTag(List<RecipeTag> vm)
    {

        foreach (var tag in vm)
        {
            RecipeTag recipeTag = new RecipeTag();
            recipeTag.Name = tag.Name;
            recipeTag.RecipeId = tag.RecipeId;
            db.RecipeTags.Add(tag);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(vm, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

By this, you define the class of your function. This class can be made EF-compatible or you copy the fields to you calss RecipeTag.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think I need to use DataContract. My problem was my post script.